# Get rid of annoying output

Tags: python, subprocess, output, moviepy

I'm working with the following function:

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip

if ffmpeg_extract_subclip("c:\\users\\samuel\\desktop\\VideosYT\\randomvideo.mp4", 0, 10, targetname="test.mp4"):
  print("")
```

which is giving me the following output:

```
Moviepy - Running:
>>> "+ " ".join(cmd)
Moviepy - Command successful
```

which I don't want it to show in my terminal.

How can I solve this output problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `logger` parameter of the function after I searched for the source code. Here's [a link](https://moviepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/ffmpeg.html)!

You can try to set it to `None`:

```
if ffmpeg_extract_subclip("c:\\users\\samuel\\desktop\\VideosYT\\randomvideo.mp4", 0, 10, targetname="test.mp4", logger=None):
  print("")
```